# Any benefit to switching to Wireless N?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I'm subscribed to BrightHouse "High Speed Online" service. I've measured the speed of the connection [here](http://www.internetfrog.com/mypc/speedtest/). It is 9.57 Mbps downstream and  2.73 Mbps upstream. Is there any benefit to upgrading my router and WiFi dongle to 802.11n? Right now I am using 802.11g per my Linksys WRT54GL router and WUSB54G dongle. Thanks.

Comment: If you're transferring data between computers and one of the computers is wireless, then yes. If there are lots of wireless networks in the area, then also yes.

Comment: Just to clarify: which of their service do you pay for now? Standard, Turbo or Lightning?? If you are paying for Turbo then you're not getting your full speed at the moment with your WiFi. Standard is 10/1 Mbps. Turbo is 30/2 (See [here](http://brighthouse.com/corporate/shop/internet)) BTW You **need** to do this test with a cabled connection (not over WiFi) to get a good comparison if you **could** get a higher speed with WiFi.

Comment: 802.11N is more than 10 faster then 802.11G

Comment: Do the test again but then wired. Also use several different speedtest-sites because i got 5 down and 1.5 up with your site (while i have a 150/15 Mbps service which i also get when using other tests like http://speedtest.net and download of files)

Comment: @Ramhound: 10 what, times?

Comment: @Xavierjazz would any other word fit?

Comment: Well, I've been told that less is more.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't measure when plugged in using a cable. I'm also not sure what service I am subscribed to. AFAIK I just picked the most basic service at $29.99/mo in my area. I'll see about hooking up my PC to the actual cable next.

Comment: :necro:

My download speed is 10.01Mbps and my upload speed is 1.16Mbps when connected directly to the modem using a cable.

Answer (score 1):

**802.11g** Bandwidth (net): **19MBit/s** & Radius: ca. **38m**

**802.11n** Bandwidth (net): **240MBit/s** & Radius: ca. **70m**

So, doing anything in parallel like streaming data (device to device, not internet related)to other devices in your lan will see its limits very fast using 802.11g. Add to that the fact that 802.11n will give you a larger operating radius (think of all those corners of your home you want to get wifi in).

Short answer: Yes, strong benefit.

Comment: Quote: "...any benefit..."

Comment: No internet streaming benefit, but they will get better range inside their house, which is always nice. Probably not worth upgrading it if you have one of those rare houses where the wifi already reaches everywhere.

Comment: Right. I am just thinking, if he/she wants to stream some local data to his wifi capable tv or if streaming some youtube content maxing out the internet connection....there's not much headroom for anything else, in which case the internet bandwidth won't reach its full potential or the lan performance is sluggish.

Comment: @Moses Not certain if OP has 10Mbps down. I think he/she did the test via WiFi (while it should be done wired). The Standard service of BrightHouse is 1 up (and he/she got almost 3) so i think he/she got Turbo (30/2) or Lightning (60/5) and then it becomes a whole new story.

Comment: These numbers are misleading. 802.11g throughput in a clean environment often reaches around 23 mbps even without frame bursting. 802.11n comes in lots of flavors (1, 2, and 3 spatial streams; 20 or 40MHz channel widths; short or long guard intervals) for top PHY rates anywhere from 65 to 450 mbps, with "net bandwidth" (TCP throughput) from 52 to 360 mbps. Estimating ranges for Wi-Fi is unwise. This Answer assumes all 802.11n is MIMO, which isn't true. MIMO helps with range, all else being equal, but all else is never equal, and there is plenty of non-MIMO 802.11n gear out there.

Answer (score -2):

No.  Unless you're using a very old router, no benefit because your bottleneck speed is the 10MBPS from your provider.  Even a B class wifi would work fine, but G and N would be identical.  Other answers that advise you to spend the money on a new router are assuming that you have multiple computers on the network AND that you are transferring data BETWEEN them (multiple computers downloading from the internet will not benefit from the upgrade).

Comment: A new router and a new modem with 1000/100/10 ports would make a different an old router would have 100/10 ports and would make a difference. 802.11b is really really slow and while the downstream to the router would not be effected by an upgrade the transmission to the laptop **Would be**